# Return an exception with the Result type

Tags: f#

I'm trying use the errors that F# has by default: the exceptions.

I want handle the errors with the Result type, but if I try return a specialization of Exception, like ArgumentException, as error, Visual Studio says "this function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected".

My source:

```
let division (x: float) (y: float): Result<float, Exception> =
    if x = 0.0 then
        Error (ArgumentException ())
    else
        Ok (x / y)
```

Comment: Your code is not consistent. The arguments are `x` and `y`, but you divide `a` and `b`. You are checking for zero on `x`, is that then the denominator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the type of newly created `ArgumentException` is not the same as the `Exception` type which you specified in the type signature.

You can cast `ArgumentException` to `Exception` safely using the `:>` operator, but F# does not insert the cast automatically, so you have to write it yourself:

```
let division (x: float) (y: float): Result<float, Exception> =
    if x = 0.0 then
        Error (ArgumentException () :> Exception)
    else
        Ok (x / y)
```

In fact, F# can even infer the target type from the type annotation, so you can write just:

```
Error (ArgumentException () :> _)
```

PS: I see that you are saying you're getting "the function takes too many arguments" error. This is quite strange and perhaps there is something more going on in your case. The error that I get when I try your code is "This expression was expected to have type `Exception` but was `ArgumentException`" so perhaps you are also redefining some of the standard types...

Comment: The message "the function takes too many arguments" refers to an earlier version of the OP's code where the construction of the error case looked like `Error ArgumentException`. Apparently the OP changed the code, but neglected to change the question text.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Rather than casting to a wildcard, you could change the type to float -> float -> Result<float, ArgumentException> as this is more meaningful than just Exception

Answer (score 3):

You mixed up types and values (update: this answer refers mostly to the first version of your post, TomasP's answer is better for the updated code)

- In the method signature, `Exception` is the type argument to the generic `Result` type.
- In the method body, when you construct your return value, you need to call `Error` with an *instance* of the `Exception` type.

You need to actually invoke the operation that could throw (`x/y` usually does not, as pointed out in the comments), catch the exception, and then return that:

```
let division (x: float) (y: float): Result<float, Exception> =
    try
        let result = SomethingThatCouldThrow x y
        Ok result
    with 
    | e -> Error e
```

Btw, I do not understand your goal of "use the errors that F# has by default: the exceptions." The .Net default handling of an error condition is exceptions, yes. But what you are returning here a class that wraps the exception (in the error case).

Comment: I understand you want say, but I don't want throw or check exceptions, I only want wrap an exception inside the Result type (instead of use an "enum"). F# hasn't the "new" keyword, so I should use parentehesis for the object creation (I've edited my post). The problem is that I can't return a specialization of Exception, as ArgumentException, for example.

Comment: F# does indeed allow you to create a new instance of an object with the `new` keyword. I was able to create an instance using `let e = new System.ArgumentException("y")` (Assuming you want to preemptively check for division by zero).

Comment: @Eric If I try to return "Error e", the problem is the same: "This expression was expected to have type 'Exception' but here has type 'ArgumentException'".

Comment: You'll have to cast the `ArgumentException` to an `Exception` using the `:>` cast operator. I just did something like this in F# Interactive: `let (e2: Result<string, System.Exception>) = Error (System.ArgumentException("y") :> System.Exception);;`

Comment: FYI with normal flags `1.0 / 0.0` doesn't throw instead it returns: `inf`. Not even `0.0 / 0.0` throws, it becomes `nan`.